# PHP-MYSQL: Converting Unix Timestamp to DateTime and vice versa

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp

im using php 5.4.6 and MySQL 5.5.29 and I get trouble by converting a UNIX TIMESTAMP to MYSQL DATETIME and vice versa. Mysql and php wun on the same local machine.

I have a simple mysql table

```
CREATE TABLE Entry(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
created DATETIME NOT NULL);
```

To insert data I use php PDO and mysql NOW(). This works fine, the correct datetime is stored in the database.

My plan is to work with unix timestamps on client side (php & mysql on server side).

So I would like to deliver unix timestamps to my client. 
Therefore I use MySql UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function to convert it directly in the query.

So a sample query looks like this:

```
SELECT created, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) AS TS FROM Entry
```

The result:
created = 2013-02-14 20:47:35
TS = 1360871255

So now I want to do the other way, I pass the a UNIX Timestamp, and want to compare it with Entries in my Database. Unfortunetly Im not able to write a PHP script that works. I don't know why, but when I m passing the same timestamp (1360871255) to PHP I do not get 2013-02-14 20:47:35 with this method:

```
public static function toDateTime($unixTimestamp){
    return date("Y-m-d H:m:s", $unixTimestamp);
}
```

When I call toDateTime(1360871255) will return 2013-02-14 20:02:35 which is not the original DateTime.

I know, I dont need to format 1360871255 to a Y-m-d H:m:s to use it in MYSQL, but 1360871255 seems not to be the time that I expected (and MYSQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP has returned).

What I want to do is a simple query that shows me Entries that are older  than a certain timestamp, something simple like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Entry WHERE created < 1360871255
```

but as I mentioned before, the query result is not the expected, because 1360871255 seems not to be the correct time.

I do not specify any special timezone for the mysql connection in php.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your [date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is wrong... `i` is for minute,  not `m` (months).

```
return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixTimestamp);
```

A few side notes:

- There's no need to re-assign, i.e. `$unixTimestamp = $unixTimestamp;`
- Since you're using PHP > 5.3. you may be interested in the new [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object.

Comment: @sockeqwe - You are not stupid. You just over-looked it. It happens.

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in the function you wrote:

```
return date("Y-m-d H:m:s", $unixTimestamp);
```

You specify month(m) in both the date and time portions. You should replace the second *m* with *i*, the correct flag for hours when using date() in PHP.

```
return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixTimestamp);
```

Depending on your needs you might find the PHP function strtotime() useful enough.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use the FROM_UNIXTIME function in mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function format_date($str) {
    $month = array(" ", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
    $y = explode(' ', $str);
    $x = explode('-', $y[0]);
    $date = "";    
    $m = (int)$x[1];
    $m = $month[$m];
    $st = array(1, 21, 31);
    $nd = array(2, 22);
    $rd = array(3, 23);
    if(in_array( $x[2], $st)) {
            $date = $x[2].'st';
    }
    else if(in_array( $x[2], $nd)) {
            $date .= $x[2].'nd';
    }
    else if(in_array( $x[2], $rd)) {
            $date .= $x[2].'rd';
    }
    else {
            $date .= $x[2].'th';
    }
    $date .= ' ' . $m . ', ' . $x[0];

    return $date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nothing of both. you should save the timestamp as an `INT` or `BIGINT` because if you use the `TIMESTAMP` format of mysql you will never ever get it back to an `int`. You can only get something like this `1970-01-01 01:00:00`.